# Active directory service setup

Tags: java, active-directory, jetty, kerberos

I am new to active directory programming. I need to set up a service which only an authenticated active directory user can use. I have been reading the msdn docs. My idea of the whole set up is as follows now,

1. I have added my pc in the AD domain, I have created the user. (both manually)
2. I wrote a simple REST service which returns "Hello world" on a GET call. I have read about "service publication" in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/publishing-with-service-connection-points. Though do not know right now how can I register my REST service as a active directory object. Any example/lead in that direction would be helpful.
3. What I finally want to do is similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/mutual-authentication-using-kerberos

> a client application uses a service instance's service connection point (SCP) object in Active Directory Domain Services to retrieve data from which to compose an SPN for the service.

So my main question is it possible to register a web service like my example to be registered as an active directory "domain enabled" service?

If you need more details on the context please let me know. If this question is too easy for you, then I apologize in advance, I looked around for some days by now, it is still not clear to me yet :(

Comment: If your web service is running in IIS on Windows, then it's super easy. IIS handles the actual authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/ How you get the user information in your application depends on what your application is written in. For ASP.NET, you can get the username with `HttpContext.Current.User`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I do not have much idea how to include my service in windows IIS. As of now the service is running in a separate remote server.

Comment: What is the remote server running? The implementation is dependent on the web server software you are running.

Comment: I think answer to your question is Jetty web server. The simple REST code is written in Java.

Comment: I'm not a Java developer, and I've never used Jetty, so I can't help there. But I added the jetty and java tags to your question, so it might catch the attention of someone who can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 options

- as you have a java service it's served from some java http server being jetty, tomcat, netty or whatever else. Configure your http server to authenticate/authorize against windows domain using Kerberos or NTLM or both depending on the MS environment you work in. Depending on the http server you use you can find some integration howtos server specific like e.g. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-auth-howto.html or check the general java howtos e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/single-sign-using-kerberos-java1.htm
- or you can use an existing (if it's there of course) IIS as a proxy for you service and configure authentication/authorization there as it has necessary integrations ootb

In both cases you will need to deal with a AD account for you service/http server, a SPN (e.g HTTP/yourservice.com) bound to this account and a keytab.

The rest depends on the level of integration you want to achieve.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I read some more about this, we do not have any IIS running so that is not the direction we want to go. But it seems I need to set up my Jetty to authenticate using Kerberos or SPNEGO somehow. I will read about it. However, my next doubt that remains is how to register my web service as a service in the AD domain and set up a service connection point.

Comment: Hey Haramoz, please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/service-publication for more details. Btw what will be a client of your service?